# SAML Digest verification failed

Tags: php, ssl, saml, verification, digest

I have a PHP script which acts as the IdP in the SAML authentication process.  The PHP script generates a SAML response, which goes to our vendor (service.com).  However, I keep getting an "ID6018: Digest verification failed for reference" error message.

For the certificate, I am using a 2048 bit self-signed RSA certificate generated through openssl.  The vendor has the same certificate and its public key loaded on their SP.

This is the PHP code which generates and signs the SAML response:

```
$response_params = array();
$time = time();
$response_params['IssueInstant'] = samlGetDateTime(time());
$response_params['NotOnOrAfter'] = $notOnOrAfter;
$response_params['NotBefore'] = $notBefore;
$response_params['AuthnInstant'] = samlGetDateTime(time());
$response_params['SessionNotOnOrAfter'] = samlGetDateTime(time());

$response_params['ID'] = samlCreateId();
$response_params['assertID'] = samlCreateId();

$response_params['issuer'] = $issuer;
$response_params['email'] = $authenticatedUser;
$response_params['x509'] = <<<X509
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
X509;

$private_key = <<<RSA_PRIVATE_KEY
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
RSA_PRIVATE_KEY;

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');

$resp = $xml->createElementNS('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol', 'samlp:Response');

$resp->setAttribute('xmlns:saml', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion');
$resp->setAttribute('ID',$response_params['ID']);
$resp->setAttribute('Version','2.0');
$resp->setAttribute('IssueInstant',$response_params['IssueInstant']);
$resp->setAttribute('Destination',$destination);
$resp->setAttribute('InResponseTo',$requestID);
$xml->appendChild($resp);

$issuer = $xml->createElementNS('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion','samlp:Issuer',$response_params['issuer']);
$resp->appendChild($issuer);

$status = $xml->createElementNS('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol','samlp:Status');
$resp->appendChild($status);

$statusCode = $xml->createElementNS('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol','samlp:StatusCode');
$statusCode->setAttribute('Value', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success');
$status->appendChild($statusCode);

$assertion = $xml->createElementNS('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion','saml:Assertion');
$assertion->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:saml', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion');
$assertion->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$assertion->setAttribute('xmlns:xs', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$assertion->setAttribute('ID',$response_params['assertID']);
$assertion->setAttribute('Version','2.0');
$assertion->setAttribute('IssueInstant',$response_params['IssueInstant']);
$resp->appendChild($assertion);

$assertion->appendChild($xml->createElement('saml:Issuer',$response_params['issuer']));

$subject = $xml->createElement('saml:Subject');
$assertion->appendChild($subject);

$nameid = $xml->createElement('saml:NameID',$response_params['email']);

$nameid->setAttribute('Format','urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:email');
$nameid->setAttribute('SPNameQualifier','https://service.com/adfs/ls/');
$subject->appendChild($nameid);

$confirmation = $xml->createElement('saml:SubjectConfirmation');
$confirmation->setAttribute('Method','urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer');
$subject->appendChild($confirmation);

$confirmationdata = $xml->createElement('saml:SubjectConfirmationData');
$confirmationdata->setAttribute('InResponseTo',$requestID);
$confirmationdata->setAttribute('NotOnOrAfter',$response_params['NotOnOrAfter']);
$confirmationdata->setAttribute('Recipient',$destination);
$confirmation->appendChild($confirmationdata);

$condition = $xml->createElement('saml:Conditions');
$condition->setAttribute('NotBefore',$response_params['NotBefore']);
$condition->setAttribute('NotOnOrAfter',$response_params['NotOnOrAfter']);
$assertion->appendChild($condition);

$audiencer = $xml->createElement('saml:AudienceRestriction');
$condition->appendChild($audiencer);

$audience = $xml->createElement('saml:Audience','http://service.com/adfs/services/trust');
$audiencer->appendChild($audience);

$authnstat = $xml->createElement('saml:AuthnStatement');
$authnstat->setAttribute('AuthnInstant',$response_params['AuthnInstant']);
$authnstat->setAttribute('SessionIndex','_'.samlCreateId());//$response_params['assertID']
$authnstat->setAttribute('SessionNotOnOrAfter',$response_params['SessionNotOnOrAfter']);
$assertion->appendChild($authnstat);

$authncontext = $xml->createElement('saml:AuthnContext');
$authnstat->appendChild($authncontext);

$authncontext_ref = $xml->createElement('saml:AuthnContextClassRef','urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password');
$authncontext->appendChild($authncontext_ref);

$attrStatement = $xml->createElement('saml:AttributeStatement');
$attr = $xml->createElement('saml:Attribute');
$attr->setAttribute('Name', 'mail');
$attr->setAttribute('NameFormat', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic');
$attrValue = $xml->createElement('saml:AttributeValue', $response_params['email']);
$attrValue->setAttribute('xsi:type', 'xs:string');
$attr->appendChild($attrValue);
$attrStatement->appendChild($attr);

$attr = $xml->createElement('saml:Attribute');
$attr->setAttribute('Name', 'preferredLanguage');
$attr->setAttribute('NameFormat', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic');
$attrValue = $xml->createElement('saml:AttributeValue', 'en');
$attrValue->setAttribute('xsi:type', 'xs:string');
$attr->appendChild($attrValue);
$attrStatement->appendChild($attr);
$assertion->appendChild($attrStatement);

//Private KEY
$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type' => 'private'));
$objKey->loadKey($private_key);

//Sign the Assertion
$objXMLSecDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();
$objXMLSecDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::EXC_C14N);
$objXMLSecDSig->addReferenceList(array($assertion), XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1,
array('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature', XMLSecurityDSig::EXC_C14N),array('id_name'=>'ID')); 
$objXMLSecDSig->sign($objKey);
$objXMLSecDSig->add509Cert($response_params['x509']);

$objXMLSecDSig->insertSignature($assertion,$subject);

$r = $xml->saveXML();

return $r;
```

This is the SAML response created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="hlboelmomjlpigfakcaaenjnkfdeldibobmfddaa" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-04-27T18:20:17Z" Destination="https://service.com/adfs/ls/" InResponseTo="id-694bef3c-da75-402a-9275-0f6170ace280">
    <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">PHP_URL</samlp:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="pfx3116ddd8-61a9-5c07-70ba-abc1781ebc0d" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-04-27T18:20:17Z">
        <saml:Issuer>PHP_URL</saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#pfx3116ddd8-61a9-5c07-70ba-abc1781ebc0d">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>m89OYak6/qfoES3ncu1bgXkef9Q=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>PXkGpH8aKgGf+iQpqN57OJvtS3+m0EsHcY+J8H6mC8S/KfHQzwtHXsLK4Pz6ykH0HTX0gsM3js24NqOciylrSvuBEo8QjA8Jk5prNnU5Xbv5u0oyjCQmx5eeBhwgsJ4DolTuM2kHskYcUtcDEdcQLmj6CsgfWmn3D4tf1t6T0LzZVFy3RnAcdUFhC/BAHI1a20ddTjoygJYCuxh8MdwQ6uAmpIGKSVHrRB1FJas4mz277+jz2JleUq8fYGfjZNVrAkWX7+OW+vFwEfW+FcthHU0kslifnLEeY749O4oOPBsOD+f+vB7dfOXztztCB/SAeTVhntb5AktbLBBnvxHiXQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>CERTIFICATE</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:email" SPNameQualifier="https://service.com/adfs/ls/">myemail@domain.com</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id-694bef3c-da75-402a-9275-0f6170ace280" NotOnOrAfter="2016-04-27T18:30:17Z" Recipient="https://service.com/adfs/ls/"/>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2016-04-27T18:10:17Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-04-27T18:30:17Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>http://service.com/adfs/services/trust</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-04-27T18:20:17Z" SessionIndex="_blfhnlolcoogjokbahplfacoehddoglankhaedgg" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2016-04-27T18:20:17Z">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">myemail@domain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="preferredLanguage" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">en</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!